# How to use lapply correctly with Bloomberg Rblpapi package to pull multiple groups of tickers

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

I am not sure if this is an lapply question or a question about the Rblpapi syntax. Rblpapi is a fantastic package to use for extracting data from bloomberg via R.

Because not everyone has bloomberg access and because there are many tickers involved, this makes providing a reproducible example more challenging so hopefully someone can offer a solution without a reprex.

When I used the following code, I can successfully pull the data I want to:

```
library(Rblpapi)
library(tidyverse)

# Connect to Bloomberg  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  blpConnect()


# Specify beginning and end dates
beg_date <- as.Date("1927-12-30", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date <- Sys.Date()


# Specify Bloomberg field to pull
my_field <- "PX_LAST"


# Call ticker script to load tickers
source(file.path(my_path, "tickers.R"), echo = FALSE)

 
# Create function to pull Bloomberg data
pull_fx <- function(input_tickers, input_field) {
  df <- as.data.frame(
    bdh(
      input_tickers,
      input_field,
      start.date               = beg_date,
      end.date                 = end_date,
      include.non.trading.days = TRUE
    )
  )
}

# Pull data  
rates_level_df         <- pull_fx(rates_tickers_level, my_field)
equity_level_us_df     <- pull_fx(equity_tickers_us_level, my_field)
```

When I attempt to pull the data with all of the tickers so I don't have to keep repeating the `pull_fx(tickers_here, my_field)` code for each set of tickers, I tried this:

```
list_df <- lapply(tickers_all, pull_fx, input_field = my_field)
```

where `tickers_all` is a character vector with all of the ticker groupings (e.g., "rates_tickers_level").  I get a list of data frames back for each ticker collection, but each data frame in the list is empty.  As a result, I can't tell if I am just using lapply incorrectly or if I providing the wrong syntax for  using lapply with the bdh command (Rblpapi package).

The output I was expecting was a list of data frames with the data pulled for each set of tickers (i.e., the "rates_level_df", "equity_level_us_df", etc. data frames that are included in the tickers_all character vector.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What is `rates_tickers_level` or `equity_tickers_us_level` ? What does it consist of? Does this work `list_df <- lapply(tickers_all, function(x) pull_fx(as.name(x), my_field))` ?

Comment: They are character vectors that hold a series of tickers.  For example, rates_tickers_level = (rate_ticker1, rate_ticker2, rate_ticker3...)

Comment: So `length(rates_tickers_level)` is more than 1 ?

Comment: Yes, more than 1.

Comment: What is `class(tickers_all)` and `length(tickers_all)` ?

Comment: Character class.  Length = 27.   The lapply line gives me 27 data frames that have Date and Price columns with no values.   If I use the rates_level_df line I get populated values returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mget` with `tickers_all`

```
list_df <- lapply(mget(tickers_all), pull_fx, input_field = my_field)
```

To understand why we need `mget` here consider this simple example

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
tmp <- c('a', 'b')
tmp
#[1] "a" "b"
```

`tmp` has variables `a` and `b` which are stored as strings in them. To get value 1 and 2 which are stored in `a` and `b` we need `mget`.

```
mget(tmp)
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Perfect!  Can you please explain why I needed `mget` here?

Comment: I added a simple example to demonstrate the need of `mget` here.